# How to load latest Class from two different projects

Tags: php, class, reusability, code-reuse

Consider below example. I have two projects. I have used common class `c` in both project. I want to load the latest class `c` from anyone of the project.

E.g.

**Project 1:**

```
class a {
}

if ( ! class_exists( 'c' ) ) :
    class c {
        static $version = '1.0.0';
    }
}
```

**Project 2:**

```
class b {
}

if ( ! class_exists( 'c' ) ) :
    class c {
        static $version = '1.0.2';
    }
}
```

In above example, I'm expecting to load the class `c` from `Project 2` in both projects because it has latest `1.0.2`.

Any suggestions? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Seems more like a Source/Library management issue to me rather than a job for your PHP code itself

Comment: If two projects both know about both codebases, I'd say they're actually one project. Fundamentally, you're looking for [a package manager](https://getcomposer.org/). Each project should pull in `C` as a **dependency**, rather than having a hard copy saved locally.

Comment: I have not tried to create such dependency with `composer` but its maybe the solution. Thanks for the comments. :)

Comment: You don't necessarily have to migrate to a full package manager solution immediately, but the concept is important. A shared dependency *should be stored separately* - this can be anything from a dedicated repository to a separate directory on disk. What you're trying to avoid is having your dependencies stored directly in the projects that use it, because they'll quickly become out of sync with the latest version.